# Kotlin immutable entities changing unexpectedly when using it with JPA

Tags: jpa, kotlin

In our project we are using kotlin with JPA. All of our entities are immutable so, it is not possible to set fields of our entities directly. You have to create a new instance by using the copy method. If you want these changes to be reflected to database, you must persist this newly created entity with an explicit function call.

In the beginning, this approach looks perfect to us. However, nowadays we are having some problems like some of our instances are changing unexpectedly in the memory.

```
val instance1 = repository.findById(entityId)
repository.save(instance1.copy(deletedAt = Instant.now()))
..
..
assertNull(instance1.deletedAt())
```

In the code snipped above, instance1 is retrieved from database and its deletedAt field is set with copy method and the new instance which is created with this copy method is passed to save method of the repository. We don't set any field of instance1, we create a new instance to do these changes. However, the result on assert line is unexpectedly not-null.

It seems, There is a confliction on JPA persistence context (first level cache) and kotlin's immutable and copy method logic.

Is anyone facing this problem or any suggestion or best practices when using JPA and immutable Kotlin entities?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you're ignoring the return value from `save()`.  Its docs say:

> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

But you're not doing that; you're instead continuing to use the original instance which (as that says) may have changed.

Instead, store the return value from `save()`, and use that thereafter.  (Either by making `instance1` a `var`, or creating a new `val` and not referring to `instance1` afterward.)

(This isn't a Kotlin-specific problem, and is exactly the same in Java.  JPA , Spring, &c work their magic by futzing with the bytecode, so can do things your code can't — such as changing immutable values.  Most of the time you can ignore it, but this case makes it obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

Immutable types are not compatible on how JPA works.

JPA works around the concept of UnitOfWork, which mean objects retrieved from the database lives in a PersistedContext (1st level cache) and they get discarded once the EntityManager is closed (on a web application at the end of the HTTP request).

When using the `copy` method in an entity you just retrieved from the database, the copied object is considered `detached` from the current session meaning that changes on it cannot be tracked by JPA and the underlying implememtation (Hibernate / EclipseLink) have hard time figuring out which SQL statement needs to be fired (Insert/Update/Delete ????)

Things got way more complex when you have complex object graph with OneToMany associations and cascading options.

So my recommendation is unfortunately is to avoid Immutable types when using JPA.